# How to properly render external texture in Sceneform 1.16.0?

Tags: java, android, sceneform

Previously there was a
[nice article for rendering external texture](https://medium.com/krootl/arcore-sceneform-simple-video-playback-3fe2f909bfbc)

None of the code will work with Sceneform 1.16.0, as there are no .sfb, .sfm or .sfa formats.
New material seems to be in .matc format which is not human readable. How to create or modify a material in this version of Sceneform?

Using [sceneform_camera_material.matc](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/sceneformsrc/sceneform/src/main/res/raw/sceneform_camera_material.matc) its possible to render a camera to background of Sceneform, but its very pixelated, irrespective of whatever camera preview resolution chosen. GLTF models looks great when loaded, issue is specific to external texture.

Is this some issue related to Linear filtering of textures or something to do with material settings of Google Filament?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Year since I last touched the ARCore & Sceneform, and now everything is outdated and broken. Looking through the internet for answers and stumbling upon this question referencing my post on Medium. Thanks :) I'm also lost. Just will not bump ARCore version in my project, hope it will work for some time. Big finger to AR Google management.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Sceneform 1.16 and want to create `sceneform.rendering.Material`,

(1)
You need to create your own matc file with Filmaent matc tool. You can download filament tool at https://github.com/google/filament/releases.

(2)
After you create your own matc file, put it in android raw directory, and call

```
  com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Material.builder()
            .setSource(context, R.raw.YOUR_MATC_FILE)
            .build()
            .thenAccept { material->
                //Do something with created sceneform's Material
            }
            .exceptionally { throwable: Throwable? ->
 
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was able to create augmented_video_material.matc from the article mentioned in question. But still the camera preview is pixelated.

Comment: Managed to bring a good quality camera preview by using a modified version of sceneform_opaque_textured_material.matc, but not the proper way, it is creating Textures @30FPS and assigning it to a Sceneform node.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you are trying to fix?

Comment: The pixellated external texture rendering issue. Can't pinpoint why it is happening, ARCore uses the same material so I can assume it's not an issue with material. I am creating an external texture and addTarget that external texture's surface using CaptureRequest.Builder, thereby rendering camera preview. Its working but it looks like  resolution lower than 200x200

Comment: oh, yeah. Filament only supports Linear - Linear / Nearest - Nearest filtering. But I don't think it's the filtering issue.
Maybe you should go check sceneform_opaque_textured_material.matc's fragment part.

Comment: I compiled my `.mat` to `.matc` using the matc compiler for Mac, then placed it in the raw package. I used your code but for some reason I keep getting `E/Filament: in static filament::MaterialParser *filament::details::FMaterial::createParser(backend::Backend, const void *, size_t):480
    reason: could not parse the material package`